# Load related data with IgnoreQueryFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

What is the best way to Update all related Entities when working with Queryfilter?

All my Entities inherit from a BaseClass with "IsDeleted" Property.

When i build my Context i use

```
if (table.GetProperties().Any(column => column.ClrType == typeof(bool) && column.Name == "IsDeleted"))
{
      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(table.ClrType);
      var propertyMethodInfo = typeof(EF).GetMethod("Property").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
      var isDeletedProperty = Expression.Call(propertyMethodInfo, parameter, Expression.Constant("IsDeleted"));
      BinaryExpression compareExpression = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, isDeletedProperty, Expression.Constant(false));
      var lambda = Expression.Lambda(compareExpression, parameter);
      builder.Entity(table.ClrType).HasQueryFilter(lambda);
}
```

the HasQueryfilter to Ignore all deleted Entity. SoftDelete.

When i try to Update my all Collections, i only get the filterd Collections. So its never possible to Update my IsDelete Property with a true value.

```
if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
{
    foreach (var collectionEntry in _context.Entry(dbMember).Collections)
    {
        await collectionEntry.LoadAsync();
        foreach (var o in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
        {
            var entity = o as BaseEntity;
            entity.IsDeleted = dbMember.IsDeleted;
        }
    }
}
```

What i need is something like

await collectionEntry.LoadAsync().IgnoreQueryFilters().